# If Container.DataItem.BooleanValue Then

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, repeater

Working in VB.NET, in a repeater. I only want to display part of the repeater if one the data item's fields is set to true.

I am struggling to write a line that will accomplish this but am trying along the lines of this:

```
<% If '<%# Container.DataItem.IsLive%>' Then %>
   <asp:PlaceHolder ...
<% End If%>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='Eval("IsLive")'>
...
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do that at repeater1_ItemDataBound Event:**

```
Private Sub repeater1_ItemDataBound(Sender As [Object], e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
       ' This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
       ' Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
       If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
              Dim PlaceHolder1 As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder)
        If (e.Item.DataItem).IsLive Then
          PlaceHolder1.Visible = False
        End If
       End If
End Sub
```